# How does the site's new PGN viewer work?

Tags: discussion, faq, pgn-viewer

In particular, what controls are available when playing through a game?

Comment: You might be interested in [How to add a replayer to a post?](http://meta.chess.stackexchange.com/q/179/672)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> This post is a work in progress, please feel free to add or embellish...

<sub>add link to example replayer here</sub>

There are 3 main ways to make moves using the replayer:

1. The control buttons
2. The keyboard
3. The mouse scroll wheel

### Control Buttons

- The control buttons at the bottom of the replayer should be fairly self explanatory.  You can move forward or backward, flip the board, or move to the start/end of the game.
- In order to select a variation, click the desired move when the move variation selection window appears.
- You may also click on the moves on the right of the board in order to go directly to that move.

### Keyboard Shortcuts

These keyboard shortcuts will only work when the replayer has focus, that is, after you click on it.

- <kbd>→</kbd> / <kbd>←</kbd> (**Right / Left Arrows**) - advance or backup through the game
- <kbd>↑</kbd> / <kbd>↓</kbd> (**Up/Down Arrows**) - select the variation (when the move variation selection window is visible)
- <kbd>Esc</kbd> (**Esc Key**) - close the move variation selection window
- <kbd>F</kbd> (**F Key**) - flip the board (switch white and black)
- <kbd>Home</kbd> / <kbd>S</kbd> / <kbd>H</kbd> (**Home Key, S Key, and H Key**) - move to the starting position
- <kbd>End</kbd> / <kbd>E</kbd> (**End Key and E Key**)

  - if the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (**Control Key**) is held, move to the end of the game
  - without the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (**Control Key**), move to the end of the current variation

### Mouse Scroll Wheel

- Using the scroll wheel will either advance or backup through the game (down and up respectively).
- If the move variation window is visible, the scroll wheel will force the replayer to make the currently selected move (defaults to the main line move).